# Class not found: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am new on Spring Framework. I had followed by instructions given in book Spring 4 for Professionals. In book author configured framework via xml, but I want configure it with Java. While running I'm getting **ClassNotFoundException**

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I have published my code in
[github](https://github.com/Baxtiyor1992/spring-framework-sample).
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: just try refresh you gradle dependencies

Comment: I did it many times :), but result was same

Comment: Clean up your gradle cache `~/.gradle/caches`  and import your project again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine here, `Hello World!` is printed when I run it.
How do you try to run it?
I guess you tried to do `java -jar spring-framework-example.jar`.
This of course does not work because you miss the libraries in your classpath then.

If you exchange

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.bakhtiyor.sample.Application'
    }
}
```

with

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.bakhtiyor.sample.Application'
```

and then use `gradle run`, the application works fine.

*PS: You should always use the Gradle Wrapper, even in the tiniest project. Then it is easier for others to build your project because nothing needs to be installed to build and the build always run with the Gradle version the build is designed for.*

Comment: Thank you for your quick response to my question. My project is working now with `gradle run`. One more question again, how enable _Gradle Wrapper_?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:wrapper_generation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It' working with `gradle run`. But how do I make an exportable, shareable jar now?

Comment: You don't make a "runnable" fat jar. Those have many drawbacks and are an abuse of Java that rape its possibilities. With the `application` plugin applied you use the `distZip` or `distTar` task to generate a proper distribution archive. You could of course also try to read documentation before asking such questions. ;-)